# Убрать одинаковые пары из запроса mysql

Tags: sql, база-данных

Имеется таблица с перелетами самолетов между городами. Мне нужно выяснить между какими парами городов летает самолет Boeing 777-300. Названия самолетов и их коды хранятся в таблице aircrafts. Если я вбиваю такой запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT departure_city,     arrival_city
 FROM routes r
 JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code
 WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300'
 ORDER BY 1;
```

, то получаю, что Пары городов приведены по два раза: для рейса «туда» и для рейса «обратно». 
Например, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А я хочу, чтобы было так[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну так добавь условие, что исходный больше конечного. Ну или меньше...

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Comment: кстати, как определяется, какой элемент больше а какой меньше?

Comment: *как определяется, какой элемент больше а какой меньше?* Для стрингов? в соответствии с текущим Collation.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант рас:

```
SELECT 
  departure_city,
  arrival_city
FROM routes r
   JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code
WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300'
Group by
  (crc32(departure_city)+crc32(arrival_city));
```

Вариант два:

```
SELECT
  Distinct(crc32(departure_city)+crc32(arrival_city)),
  departure_city,
  arrival_city
FROM routes r
  JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code
WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300';
```

Вариант 3,4, ....: использовать любую другую функцию которая для суммы 2х "строк" всегда будет возвращать одинаковое значение не смотря на порядок подачи аргументов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, видимо, в postgre sql функции crc32 не существует, однако идею я поняла

Comment: Вот поэтому важно указывать движок) в постгрес ничего похожего нет и остается вариант с хранимой функцией(для реализации crc или похожего алгоритма) или надо еще подумать если хранимые функции использовать невозможно)

Comment: Ясно, буду знать)